# How to extract data from EMA Alpha Vantage?

Tags: python, extract, moving-average, alpha-vantage

I'm trying to make a trading bot, and I need the latest EMA from Alpha Vantage for that. Alpha Vantage has an API that returns EMA values:

```
d= TechIndicators(key=key_alpha)
data = d.get_ema(symbol='TQQQ',time_period=10, interval='daily', series_type='close')
print(data)
```

response:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1: Symbol": "TQQQ",
        "2: Indicator": "Exponential Moving Average (EMA)",
        "3: Last Refreshed": "2022-06-27",
        "4: Interval": "daily",
        "5: Time Period": 10,
        "6: Series Type": "close",
        "7: Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Technical Analysis: EMA": {
        "2022-06-27": {
            "EMA": "26.1283"
        },
        "2022-06-24": {
            "EMA": "25.8634"
        },
        "2022-06-23": {
            "EMA": "25.3931"
        },
        "2022-06-22": {
            "EMA": "25.4071"
        },
        "2022-06-21": {
            "EMA": "25.6554"
        },
.
.
.
        "2022-06-17": {
            "EMA": "25.9388"
        },"2010-03-03": {
            "EMA": "0.4695"
        },
        "2010-03-02": {
            "EMA": "0.4651"
        },
        "2010-03-01": {
            "EMA": "0.4603"
        },
        "2010-02-26": {
            "EMA": "0.4551"
        },
        "2010-02-25": {
            "EMA": "0.4531"
        }
    }
}
```

But I get every EMA for every day. I like to extract the latest EMA when I run the code. Is it possible to only print the latest EMA?

Answer (score 0):

You have a field in your JSON (I guess the response is in JSON) called "Last Refreshed". It looks like the data of the last refresh. Therefore, you can get the latest EMA value somehow in the following way:

```py
last_update_date = d['Meta Data']['3: Last Refreshed']
ema_value = d['Technical Analysis: EMA'][last_update_date]
```

Pay attention to error handling (if the keys do not exist).